# Spring + Springfox + Header Parameters

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, springfox

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public Foo getFoo(@HeaderParam("header") final String header) {
    ...
}
```

Adding a `@HeaderParam` method parameter as above springfox picks it up and when I look at the swagger-ui it has a field for the header. This is exactly what I want. Is there a way I can tell springfox to include this header parameter on a set of methods without having to include the parameters on the method itself? What we really have going on is a servlet filter which uses the header and we'd like an easy to set it through the swagger-ui.

Comment: @HeaderParam adds a body type parameter in Swagger UI whereas the globalOperationParameters method adds a fine header type field (but is global)

Comment: For a proper header type parameter specific to one method (non global), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801442/add-a-header-parameter-in-swagger-ui-documentation-with-springfox/40801443

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could use the `globalOperationParameters`in the docket definition. For e.g.

```
new Docket(...)
            .globalOperationParameters(
        Arrays.asList(new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("header")
            .description("Description of header")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .parameterType("header")
            .required(true)
            .build()))
```

See [#22](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger2-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348630/customizing-request-header-description-in-swagger-ui-using-springfox-swagger2

Comment: @Dilip I am getting a compile error "The method newArrayList(Parameter) is undefined for the type SwaggerConfiguration" while trying to use this snippet. I am using Swagger version 2.8.0. Aything I am missing? Could you pls suggest

Comment: That snippet is defined in a bean definition method as shown . Perhaps you're not placing the snippet correctly. Also hopefully you're removing the `...` etc.

Comment: Worked for me, but I ended up creating the parameter above the Docket creation, for readability.

Comment: Great, so helpful

Comment: Can we add cookie as a header parameter @DilipKrishnan?

Comment: more on this blog https://dev.to/s2agrahari/global-header-in-swagger-ui-spring-boot-5188

Answer (score 19):

One more explained answer for same :-

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        //Adding Header
        ParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        aParameterBuilder.name("headerName").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();
        List<Parameter> aParameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();
        aParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(apiInfo()).pathMapping("").globalOperationParameters(aParameters);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it helped a lot, change last return statement to return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().pathMapping("").globalOperationParameters(aParameters);

Answer (score 1):

`globalOperationParameters` is depressed, use `RequestParameter` and `globalRequestParameters` with `springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0`

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        List<RequestParameter> aParameters = new ArrayList<>();

        RequestParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new RequestParameterBuilder();
        aParameterBuilder.name("appId").in(ParameterType.HEADER).required(true);
        aParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());
        aParameterBuilder.name("appSecret");
        aParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*")).build().pathMapping("")
                .globalRequestParameters(aParameters);
    }
```