# Spring Boot: How to specify the PasswordEncoder?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently I got the main class:

```java
package com.recweb.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
/*@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})*/
public class SpringbootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

a members class (id, firstname..), a MemberController class:

```java
package com.recweb.springboot;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MemberController {
    @GetMapping("/members")
    public List<Member> getAllUsers() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Member(1, "amit"));
    }
}
```

and a WebSecurityConfig class:

```java
package com.recweb.springboot;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("user").roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

When i run "http://localhost:8080/members" i get a login page, i enter "user" as user & "user" as password and then i get the hardcoded Member.
It worked fine, but then i right clicked on my project-Run as-Maven install (because i added a dependency, i don't know if that was necessary, first time with Maven too).
Since then, when i enter "user" & "user" on the login page i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:196) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:86) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

and it stays on the login page.
I tried to remove the dependency & Maven install again, but no luck.
This is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.recweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!--         <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

What went wrong?
Thanks

Comment: One last try. Go to your folder `C:\Users\USER\.m2\repository` and delete it. Go back to eclipse. Maven clean -> Run as Java Application.

Comment: Why are you using SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

In `spring-security-core:5.0.0.RC1`, the default `PasswordEncoder` is built as a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`. When you store the users in memory, you are providing the passwords in plain text and when trying to retrieve the encoder from the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to validate the password it can't find one that matches the way in which these passwords were stored.

Use this way to create users instead.

```
User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("user").roles("USER").build();
```

You can also simply prefix `{noop}` to your passwords in order for the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` use the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` to validate these passwords. Notice that `NoOpPasswordEncoder` is deprecated though, as it is not a good practice to store passwords in plain text.

```
User.withUsername("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER").build();
```

For more information, check this post.

https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-encoding

Comment: Thanks, That's work for me also in XML, <security:user name="user" authorities="admin"
     password="{noop}userpassword" />

Comment: `withDefaultPasswordEncoder` has been deprecated. Anybody know what the suggested alternative is?

Comment: @zero01alpha is deprecated for the same reason NoOpPasswordEncoder was, it's not safe for production. Spring expects you to only use it for sample applications. For production, this should be externalized.

Answer (score 72):

Use `NoOpPasswordEncoder` for `inMemoryAuthentication`

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("user")
    .password("{noop}password")
    .roles("USER")
```

Comment: It works but Using NoOpPasswordEncoder password is not secure.

Comment: What object type is `auth` in this example?

Comment: @Michael it is a AuthenticationManagerBuilder coming from the configurer method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Answer (score 24):

You need to have some sort of a password encoder, but

```
withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
```

is deprecated and no more suitable for production. Use this instead:

```
PasswordEncoder encoder =
     PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

...

UserDetails user = User.withUsername("someusername")
                       .password(encoder.encode("somepassword"))
                       .roles("USER").build();
```

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html

Comment: This should be accepted answer as it does answer the question

Answer (score 13):

I simply added

```
 @Bean
public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
 return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

To the configuration class

Answer (score 12):

Try this in `SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{        
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("USER")
        .and()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

Work for me

Answer (score 11):

You can use this, but be advised that `User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()` is **deprecated**:

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

    PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    final User.UserBuilder userBuilder = User.builder().passwordEncoder(encoder::encode);
    UserDetails user = userBuilder
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

    UserDetails admin = userBuilder
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER","ADMIN")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{    
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .withUser("test").password("test123").roles("USER").and()
            .withUser("test1").password("test123").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use any of the following and it will work fine:-

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin@123").roles("admin");
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("admin");
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance()).withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("admin");
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the password encoder like this:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

It's required to use the passwordEncoder for the users and also for the clients in Spring Boot 2

Check out this repository https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-2-oauth2-authorization-jwt

You can see how the passwordEncoder is set up and how to use it with users and clients in the database.

Answer (score 2):

As I have found many different upvoted answers to this question with very little explanation, I decided to provide my own answer which should provide a more in-depth understanding of how Spring Security password encoding works. I spent some time debugging the Spring code to figure out all the details.

Internally, Spring Security uses a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` when authenticating users. Assuming the credentials `user:password` are provided during login, the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` loads the stored password for this particular user and tries to determine its encoding. The `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` expects passwords to be stored in the form `{type}hash`:

```
{bcrypt}hash
{scrypt}hash
{MD5}hash
{noop}hash
...
```

If the default `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` now encounters a stored password without the `{type}`, it cannot infer which encoder to use and instead uses an `UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder` which throws an exception. This means that the exception occurs because the password is stored without any encoding information and Spring Security uses a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` which is not able to handle this.

One way to solve this issue is to also use the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to encode and store the password. The encoder retrieved with `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` will use `bcrypt` as default encoding so that the password will be stored as `{bcrypt}hash`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password(encoder.encode("password"))
        .roles("USER");
}
```

The `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` is useful when you want to handle different encodings in your project. For example, assume old passwords were stored in plain text and new passwords are now encoded with `bcrypt`. You will just have to prefix all your old stored passwords with `{noop}` and you are good to go. It would work the same if you had stored passwords encoded with MD5, just prefix them with `{MD5}`.

In a new project it would also be possible and is perfectly fine to define a specific encode like the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` instead of using the delegating one. When the encoder is registered as a bean, Spring Security will also use this encoder for authentication instead of the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`. Passwords are now stored as `bcrypt hash` without the `{type}`.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
        .roles("USER");
}
```

So you are able to chose one of the described variants. I recently went with `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` as this only requires one line of code and no bean creation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix all existing passwords with {noop} to keep the default encoder of Spring Security 5.

Example:

```
auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin!234").roles("ADMIN");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        DelegatingPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
        passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PasswordEncoder is already been deprecated so all these three approaches need to be changed :

1-  `User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("user").roles("USER").build();`

2-`User.withUsername("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER").build();`

3-`passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())`

And the new way is to use BCryptPasswordEncoder or DelegatingPasswordEncoder

we are going to use kotlin and the DelegatingPasswordEncoder  approach since it is recommended more than the BCryptPasswordEncoder approach

the DelegatingPasswordEncoder  approach should be like this :

```
val encoder= PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
             
          val user  = User
            .withUsername("khalid")
            .password(encoder.encode("12345"))
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
```

And another implementation using it with AuthenticationManagerBuilder like this:

```
 val encoder= PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
 AuthenticationManagerBuilder().inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("user")).roles("USER")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [spring security 5.0 's new feature.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/new.html)
They write [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/core-services.html#core-services-password-encoding).

> Spring Security’s PasswordEncoder interface is used to perform a one
>   way transformation of a password to allow the password to be stored
>   securely. Given PasswordEncoder is a one way transformation, it is not
>   intended when the password transformation needs to be two way (i.e.
>   storing credentials used to authenticate to a database). Typically
>   PasswordEncoder is used for storing a password that needs to be
>   compared to a user provided password at the time of authentication.

So i tried this [Mutiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity).
This s my security configuration. Hope it help you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
{
  private final EdminService edminService;
  public SecurityConfig ( final EdminService edminService ){
    this.edminService=edminService;
  }
  @Bean
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throw Exception {
    UserBuilder users= Users.withDefaultPasswordEncoder;
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    List<EdminEntity> edminList=this.edminService.findAll();
    for(EdminEntity edmin: edminList){
     manager.createUser(users.username(edmin.getEdminname())
     .password(edmin.getEdminrpass()).roles("EDMIN_ROLE").build());
    }
    return manager;
  }
  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
       .authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/home","/vendor/**","/image/**","/home/**").permitAll()
       .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("EDMIN_ROLE")
       .anyRequest().authenticated()
       .and()
       .formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login")
       .permitAll()
       .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
       .and()
       .logout()
       .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));}
   }
}
```

Sorry for my english and thanks for read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
A few days ago I have to face the same problem on spring security version (5.0.8). See the example version here:

code:

@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .withUser("farid").password("farid").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

OR

When you are configuring the ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer, you have to also apply the new password storag`enter code here`e format to the client secret.

.secret("{noop}secret")
```

you can see the link: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Password encoder , check the following sample

```
PasswordEncoder encoder =
             PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(encoder).withUser("Ahmad")
            .password("1600").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and().withUser("Belal").password("1515").roles("USER");
```

Answer (score 0):

Had `IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"` exception in my initial app loading startup housekeeper. (Just needed to normalize data in DB before the app start.) With [this (manually set an authenticated user)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336233/1032167) approach you can create `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and setAuthentication. You can get IllegalArgumentException, if you don't specify 3-rd argument `AuthorityList`.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        admin.getEmail(), 
        UserServiceImpl.PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(admin.getPassword()),
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(admin.getRoles()) // <= had to add this line to resolve the exception
);

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authReq);
```

Maybe some other setup steps could also work, but setting AuthorityList is good enough for me. And you can at least dig in this direction if can't find a solution on this page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing in Memory Authentication, here's the code on how to go about it. Tested on Spring Boot 2.3.3.RELEASE

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    static PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("testuser").password(encoder.encode("testpassword")).roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/sites.xhtml/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return encoder;

    }
}
```