# In Spring Boot Security Basic Authentication, why the default password is not getting overridden by custom ones

Tags: spring-boot

Even when I extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and override its methods: configure(HttpSecurity http) and configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) with custom users and roles and either add or remove @EnableWebSecurity annotation from this configuration concrete class, the default password is still getting generated and I cannot use http basic authentication with the custom credentials I declared inside configure() method.

I am always getting like below in the console:

## Using generated security password: a2b4b374-65d2-4d20-a965-b34c00d44de9

turning off Spring Security by excluding SecurityAutoConfiguration.class is disabling the whole security which I don't want.

## pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Security Configuration

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class BookStoreSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

## App Entry Point

```java
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.springbootsecurity.bookstore"})
    public class BookStoreApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             SpringApplication.run(BookStoreApp.class, args);
        }
    }
```

I expected that from postman I would be able to login through basic authentication of my custom credential: admin/password.

But I always get the default password at console and my declared user credentials don't ever work and always give 401 unauthorized http status

Please help me with the solution!

Comment: I see this in your code: password("{noop}password"), is that a typo?

Comment: No.... I saw it here as a help for no operation encoder for passwords. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999940/spring-boot-how-to-specify-the-passwordencoder

Comment: I also tried without {noop}. No luck with that too.