# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.12 to Spring Boot 2.0 and also to Spring Security 5 and I am trying to do authenticate via OAuth 2. But I am getting this error even after using delegate {noop}:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null

Here is my code :

SecurityConfig

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**")
                .authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/v2/api-docs","/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/webjars/**",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html", "/admin11/*", "/*.html", "/*.jsp", "/favicon.ico", "//*.html", "//*.css", "//*.js",
                "/admin11/monitoring","/proxy.jsp");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfig

```
public class Oauth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTokenStore jdbcTokenStore;
    
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return jdbcTokenStore;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        CustomTokenEnhancer converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        converter.setSigningKey("secret_api");
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
                
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/v1/oauth/token");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("app").secret("{noop}secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code").scopes("read", "write")
                .autoApprove(true).accessTokenValiditySeconds(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService

```
public interface CustomUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {

    UserDetails getByMsisdn(String msisdn);

    void initDummyUsers();
}
```

To solve this issue I tried the below questions from Stackoverflow:

[Spring Boot PasswordEncoder Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999940/spring-boot-passwordencoder-error)

Comment: public interface CustomUserDetailsService extends UserDetailsService {

 UserDetails getByMsisdn(String msisdn);

 void initDummyUsers();
}

Answer (score 0):

[The Spring Security documentation is addressing your exact problem.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-troubleshoot)

> The following error occurs when one of the passwords that are stored
> has no id as described in Password Storage Format.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped
for the id "null"
     at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:233)
     at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:196)
```

> The easiest way to resolve the error is to switch to explicitly
> provide the PasswordEncoder that you passwords are encoded with. The
> easiest way to resolve it is to figure out how your passwords are
> currently being stored and explicitly provide the correct
> PasswordEncoder.
>
> If you are migrating from Spring Security 4.2.x you can revert to the
> previous behavior by exposing a NoOpPasswordEncoder bean.

So you should be able to fix this by explicitly providing the `PasswordEncoder`

```
// remember, its bad practice
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

Or even better supply a [custom defined password encoder delegator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe):

```
String idForEncode = "bcrypt";
Map encoders = new HashMap<>();
encoders.put(idForEncode, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("noop", NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
encoders.put("pbkdf2", new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());
encoders.put("sha256", new StandardPasswordEncoder());

PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
    new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(idForEncode, encoders);
```

All taken from the [official spring security docs on password encoding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage).