# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-security

i am new at spring security and try to use spring security in my project by this error is popping continuously

this is my dao class

```
package com.voicechat.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.voicechat.entities.Credentials;
import com.voicechat.entities.Robi_nav;

public interface Robi_Dao_logIn extends JpaRepository<Credentials, Integer> {

    @Query("select c from Credentials c where c.uname = :uname")
    public Credentials getbyUname(@Param("uname") String uname);

}
```

this is my credentials class

```
package com.voicechat.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "credentials")
public class Credentials {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int Id;
    private String uname;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        role = role;
    }
    
    
    public Credentials(int id, String uname, String password, String role) {
        super();
        Id = id;
        this.uname = uname;
        this.password = password;
        role = role;
    }
    public Credentials() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Credentials [Id=" + Id + ", uname=" + uname + ", password=" + password + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }
}
```

i think the error resides in this code

```
package com.voicechat.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetailService() {

        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();

    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider provider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoautpro = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoautpro.setUserDetailsService(this.getUserDetailService());
        return daoautpro;

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("//**").hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin().and().csrf().disable();

    }

}
```

this is userdetails

```
package com.voicechat.config;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.voicechat.entities.Credentials;

public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private Credentials cred;

    public CustomUserDetails(Credentials cred) {
        super();
        this.cred = cred;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority simple = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(cred.getRole());

        return List.of(simple);

    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return cred.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {

        return cred.getUname();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is implementation of user details

```
package com.voicechat.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.voicechat.dao.Robi_Dao_logIn;
import com.voicechat.entities.Credentials;



public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    
    @Autowired
    private Robi_Dao_logIn login;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        
        Credentials cred = (Credentials) login.getbyUname(username);
        System.out.println(" "+username);
        if (cred == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");

        }
        CustomUserDetails custom=new CustomUserDetails(cred);

        return custom;
    }
    

}
```

this is error that is poping

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:254) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:202) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar:9.0.43]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

and at last this is my database in which uname and password arfe stored
[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmKEj.png)

this error is driving me crazy i did every thing to stop this but this is poping again and again basically my project is logIn system where one uname and password are manually stored and that uname and password are used to login into the web service

Comment: try to save password as `passwordEncoder.encode(passwd)` may help on this

Comment: means when you save the password from a user to your database.

Comment: this has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/a/62770774/1840146

Answer (score 2):

you have defined your password as a plain string, but then you have said you want to use `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

If you read the offical spring boot documentation [on password formats](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-format) you can see that the format you need to use when storing the password in the database is:

```
{id}encodedPassword
```

Which means that in brackets you need to define the id of wich encoder to be used when decoding the password.

here are som example passwords defined with their encoder id written between the brackets.

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG 
{noop}password 
{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc 
{scrypt}$e0801$8bWJaSu2IKSn9Z9kM+TPXfOc/9bdYSrN1oD9qfVThWEwdRTnO7re7Ei+fUZRJ68k9lTyuTeUp4of4g24hHnazw==$OAOec05+bXxvuu/1qZ6NUR+xQYvYv7BeL1QxwRpY5Pc=  
{sha256}97cde38028ad898ebc02e690819fa220e88c62e0699403e94fff291cfffaf8410849f27605abcbc0
```

Which means in your case your password needs to be stored in the following format:

```
{bcrypt}YourLongEncryptedPasswordAndNotPlainText.
```

The error you are getting is because spring fetches your user and then checks the users password to see what it is prefixed with, so it can encode the incoming password using the same encryption and then do a match with the one in the database. But when it looks at the defined password, there is no defined encoder (no brackets defining the encoder) so it throws an exception saying that it can't find one.

the easiest solution is to encrypt the password using bcrypt either using an online service or in spring boot and just print the encrypted version to the console. Take that password make sure it starts with `{bcrypt}` and insert it into the database.

Answer (score -2):

From your code I can see that you are using Bcrypt encoder. You are telling Spring security that the password are encoded using it (But actually you are not encoding it).

```
 @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }
```

In this case, You need to encode your password using BCrypt password encoder like this in that loadUserByUsername method

```
cred.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(cred.getPassword()))
```

Also autowire BCryptPasswordEncoder in the same class.

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder
```

Note: Its better if you encode password while saving it to database (Using Bcrypt encoder). So this won't be required in loadUserByUsername.

Comment: @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

  Credentials cred = (Credentials) login.getbyUname(username);
  cred.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(cred.getPassword()));
  System.out.println(" " + username);



  CustomUserDetails custom = new CustomUserDetails(cred);

  return custom;
 }

}

Comment: after using as u suggested Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.voicechat.entities.Credentials.getPassword()" because "cred" is null this error is coming

Comment: Credentials cred = (Credentials) login.getbyUname(username); null pointer check here. if this cred is null the cred.getPassword() fails

Comment: my quert is not firing up i dont know why

Comment: package com.voicechat.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.voicechat.entities.Credentials;
import com.voicechat.entities.Robi_nav;

public interface Robi_Dao_logIn extends JpaRepository<Credentials, Integer> {

 @Query("select c from Credentials c where c.uname = :uname")
 public Credentials getbyUname(@Param("uname") String uname);
 

}

Comment: Try removing @Query annotation and change method to "public Credentials findByUname(@Param("uname") String uname);"   You dont realy need query annotation for simple queries, check spring boot data jpa repository.