# Custom Header Approach for Spring Boot REST API versioning

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-rest, api-versioning

I am looking to implement **Versioning a REST API With Spring Boot and Swagger using Custom Headers**. I went through many links like below.

https://dzone.com/articles/versioning-rest-api-with-spring-boot-and-swagger

[Spring + Springfox + Header Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585643/spring-springfox-header-parameters)

[Add a header parameter in Swagger UI documentation with Springfox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801442/add-a-header-parameter-in-swagger-ui-documentation-with-springfox/40801443)

One thing look clear that my each REST endpoint has to be annotated with **Custom Header** `headers = {"X-API-VERSION=v1"}`.

Below is the my sample Rest Endpoints.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Find Employees", nickname = "Find Employees")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "For Success as well as No Data found scenerio."),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
@GetMapping(value = "/employees", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=v1"})
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> findEmployees() {
    List<Employee> EmployeeList= employeeservice.findAllEmployees();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Employee>>(EmployeeList,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Swagger Config changes/updates

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        ParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        aParameterBuilder.name("X-API-VERSION=v1").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();
        List<Parameter> operationParameters = new ArrayList<>();
        operationParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalOperationParameters(operationParameters)
                .globalResponseMessage(
                        RequestMethod.GET,
                        newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("").build()));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API Management")
                .description("Sample Description")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.test.com")
                .version("0.1")
                .build();
    }
}
```

As per this link: https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-versioning-for-rest-services, I must pass value `X-API-VERSION=v1`, but when I passed that `/employees/v1/error` endpoint is getting called and nothing has left and no controller is getting called. How to fixed this issue ?

Comment: if you are calling your api from postman is it working fine as per Version specified in Header?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Please be precise. You posted a single endpoint, mapped to `/employees`. How is `/employees/v1/error` relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how this approach works.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")
    public String getUserDefault() {
        return "getUserDefault";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=v1"})
    public String getUserV1() {
        return "getUserV1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", headers = {"X-API-VERSION=v2"})
    public String getUserV2() {
        return "getUserV2";
    }

}
```

also, you can use `GetMapping` instead of `RequestMapping`, let's test it using `curl`:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/user' --header 'X-API-VERSION: v2'

return 200 getUserV2

curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/user' --header 'X-API-VERSION: v1'

return 200 getUserV1

curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/user'

return 200 getUserDefault
```

Comment: Looks like we can use both X-API-VERSION: v1 and X-API-VERSION: v2 for a single endpoint ?

Comment: @PAA yes in this example I used it 3 times, v1, v2 and without version header

Comment: Just to make the use of V2 for example, we need to duplicate the whole code it seems. Can't we utilize under the same code?

Comment: @Mojtabye- Do you know how can we set the default Value to Custom Header if Client doesn't send it in the request ?

Comment: What if we send more headers in api call then how will it work ?